# Move to next/previous item when click on previous/next button in detailed activity

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview data obtained from web-service, when i click on listview item it takes to detailed Activity where description and image are present here when i clcik on nextbutton it should take me to next item in list similarly when click on prebutton it shuld take me to previous item in list, but now i am getting force close when i click on next/pre button, i am using BaseAdapter. following is my code

DetailedActivity

```
public class SampleDesp extends Activity   {

 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;
 ListView list;


    // JSON node keys
    static final String KEY_URL_FOR_MAP = "url_site"; 
    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_SITEURL = "url";
    private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";
    private static final String KEY_URL = "url";
     static final String KEY_SLUG1= "slug";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.sampledes);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
     // move up event handler
        ImageButton preButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.prevButton);

        preButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View view) {
               movePre();
           }
        });

        // move down event handler
        ImageButton nxtButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        nxtButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View view) {
               moveNxt();
           }
        });

         ListView list = new ListView(this);
        StationAdapter adapter1 = new StationAdapter(this, songsList);    
         list.setAdapter(adapter1);


        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();
        final String url1 = in.getStringExtra(KEY_URL);

        ImageView imgv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgdesc);
        ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(url1, imgv);


        // Get JSON values from previous intent
        String songsList1 = in.getStringExtra("song");
        int listPosition = in.getIntExtra("listPosition", 0);
        final String title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
        final String siteurl = in.getStringExtra(KEY_URL_FOR_MAP);
        String date = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DATE);
        String name = in.getStringExtra(KEY_NAME);
        final String content = in.getStringExtra(KEY_CONTENT);

        // Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
        TextView lblUrl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.url_label);

        TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
        TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);
        TextView lblCont = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content_label);

        lblName.setText(title);
        lblUrl.setText(siteurl);
        lblCost.setText(date);
        lblDesc.setText(name);
        lblCont.setText(content);
    }    

    private void movePre(){



        list.setSelection(list.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1);
    }




        // Move selected item "down" in the ViewList.
        private void moveNxt(){

            list.setSelection(list.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1);


        }
```

StationAdapter

```
class StationAdapter  extends BaseAdapter{
  private static final String TAG = null;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public StationAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
        Log.v(TAG, "Message here");
    }



    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name_label); // title
        TextView siteurl = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.url_label);
        TextView date = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.email_label); // artist name
        TextView content = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.content_label);  // duration
        TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.mobile_label); 
        // duration
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imgdesc); // thumb image

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);


        ListView list;
        // Setting all values in listview
       title.setText(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_TITLE));
      // siteurl.setText(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_SITEURL));
        date.setText(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_DATE));
        siteurl.setText(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_URL_FOR_MAP));// correct code
        ((TextView)siteurl).setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
        content.setText(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_CONTENT));
        name.setText(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_NAME));
        System.out.println("output: " +name);
       imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_URL), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

LogCat error

```
02-23 12:32:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(894): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 12:32:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(894): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 12:32:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at com.example.sampleofmain.SampleDesp.moveNxt(SampleDesp.java:137)
02-23 12:32:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at com.example.sampleofmain.SampleDesp.access$1(SampleDesp.java:135)
02-23 12:32:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at com.example.sampleofmain.SampleDesp$2.onClick(SampleDesp.java:82)
02-23 12:32:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-23 12:32:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-23 12:32:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-23 12:32:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-23 12:32:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-23 12:32:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-23 12:32:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 12:32:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-23 12:32:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-23 12:32:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-23 12:32:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Its better if you provide your log cat too.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using ListView in your DetailActivity, on clicking the the list item go to the Detailactivity and pass clicked item postion and arraylist of songs in intent, now you can display detail for selected index song, and on clicking the next or prev button just set the values from your arrylist to the textview or imgaeviews, and you are done

Comment: then what should i place inside 
   private void moveNext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       
    list.setSelection(list.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1);
   }
            });

Comment: inside moveNext get next item from your ArrayList, get update your views with that