# Change content of listview on button click(on same screen)

Tags: android, listview

So In my MainActivity There are 3 rooms(coming from server).when i click on them popup is open.This popup will having shown the list of roomId(clicked on listview item).This works fine.

Now I need like this.In popup on click of next button next roomId with api to get its module is call and update the listview.
How i do this?

Problem is:-whenever going to do always it open with new popup.

[image]

As shown in picture I need to change the content of listview on toolbar's right arrow button. 
My listview is in popup.so when i change content of listview this another new popup open for new list.

This is my 1st listview(where I load all images)

```
modules_list.setOnItemClickListener(
                        new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                                    android.view.View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {


                                editor.putInt("response_position",arg2).commit();

                                editor.putString("roomid",response.getRooms()[arg2+1].getRooms_id().getRoomId()).commit();

                                String serverURL = "http://dashboard.droidhomes.in/api/module?room_id=" + response.getRooms()[arg2].getRooms_id().getRoomId();

                                // Use AsyncTask execute Method To Prevent ANR11 Problem
                                new GetallModules().execute(serverURL);


                            }
                        });
```

GetAllmodules class to get all modules and switches of Room:-

```
private class GetallModules extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    // Required initialization

    // private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String Content;
    private String Error = null;

    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(
            MainActivity.this);

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

        Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        Dialog.show();

    }

    // Call after onPreExecute method
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

        /************ Make Post Call To Web Server ***********/
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {

            // Defined URL where to send data

            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

            // Send POST data request

            pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            editor = pref.edit();

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            String auth_token = pref.getString("auth_token", "");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth_token);

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            // Append Server Response To Content String
            Content = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Error = ex.getMessage();
        } finally {
            try {

                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

        /*****************************************************/
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

        // Close progress dialog
        // Content=Content.replaceAll("<string>","");
        // Content=Content.replaceAll("</string>", "");
        Dialog.dismiss();

        if (Error != null) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Bad request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            // uiUpdate.setText("Output : " + Error);

        } else {

            // Show Response Json On Screen (activity)
            // uiUpdate.setText(Content);

            /****************** Start Parse Response JSON Data *************/

            // String OutputData = "";
            // JSONObject jsonResponse;

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            final SearchResponse response = gson.fromJson(Content,
                    SearchResponse.class);

            if (response.getStatus() == true) {


                //response.getAuth_token()

                if (response.getModule().length > 0) {



                    LayoutInflater li1 = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
                    View promptsView = li1.inflate(R.layout.prompts_modulesdialog1, null);

                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                    ListView list_modules = (ListView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.lv_modules);
                    TextView tv_roomname = (TextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.tv_roomName);

                    ImageView iv_left=(ImageView)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.iv_left);
                    ImageView iv_right=(ImageView)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.iv_right);

                    ArrayList<String> switches = new ArrayList<String>();

                    iv_right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {


                            String room_id=pref.getString("roomid","");

                            String serverURL = "http://dashboard.droidhomes.in/api/module?room_id=" + room_id;

                            // Use AsyncTask execute Method To Prevent ANR11 Problem
                            new GetallModules().execute(serverURL);




                        }
                    });
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.getModule().length; i++) {

                        tv_roomname.setText(response.getModule()[i].getRoom_title());

                        for (int j = 0; j < response.getModule()[i].getSwitches().length; j++) {
                            if (response.getModule()[i].getModule_name().equals(response.getModule()[i].getSwitches()[j].getModule_name_switches())) {

                                switches.add(response.getModule()[i].getSwitches()[j].getSwitch_name());

                            }


                        }


                    }
                    ToggleButtonListAdapter t1=new ToggleButtonListAdapter(MainActivity.this, switches);
                    list_modules.setAdapter(t1);

                    t1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();


                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No module defined for this room!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                }

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "status:-" + response.getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }

    }

}
```

[Same Scenario like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15037463/5263803)

please help me!!

Comment: Just change the adapter of list view on clicking of button...

Comment: @Chirag.T:-I dont want like this. wait i post some code so u get better idea.

Comment: @sagarpotdar call GetallModules task when you click button of dialog.

Comment: @keyur9779 yes i do this but same output comes.

Comment: @sagarpotdar create dialog object in class, dismiss it on onClick of right button.
In OnPost method just parse the res. update it in list and notify list adapter for data change. instead of creating dialog again show dialog that is already created.

Comment: @keyur9779 ok thanks.How i create dialog object in a class??                         AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
     alertDialog.show();

Comment: Sorry not understand.

Comment: AlertDialog alertDialog;

oncreate(){alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
}

onpost(){ 
// load list notify list data change 
// show list dialog with list
alertDialog.show();
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137643/discussion-between-sagar-potdar-and-keyur9779).